# Sqoop export to SQL server - Can't parse string value (NTL-NATIONAL)

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, hive, sqoop

I am trying to export Hive table by using Sqoop to SQL server.  I have a string field in hive table and the format of this field in SQL server is varchar(255).  While running the following Sqoop export:

```
sqoop export -Dmapreduce.job.queuename=default
 --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://IPaddress:portnumber;databasename=mydbname'
 --username xxx 
 --password  xxx 
 --table tablename 
 --export-dir /hive_directory/tablename 
 --columns all_my_columns 
 --input-fields-terminated-by '^' 
 --input-null-string "\\\\N" --input-null-non-string "\\\\N"
```

I get below error.  The field values are like… NTL-NATIONAL.  Appreciate any thoughts to parse this value. Thank you.

```
INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1468858380028_769962_m_000002_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.io.IOException: Can't export data, please check failed map task logs
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:112)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:39)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:146)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper.run(AutoProgressMapper.java:64)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't parse input data: 'NTL-NATIONAL'
        at test_fnl.__loadFromFields(test_fnl.java:1109)
        at test_fnl.parse(test_fnl.java:952)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:83)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:854)
        at test_fnl.__loadFromFields(test_fnl.java:1104)
        ... 12 more
```

Comment: you want to export data to 1 column `all_my_columns`. Right? Can you share sample data from `/hive_directory/tablename`

Comment: there are almost 21 columns which are string format and I am trying to export them to SQL server.  Here is the sample data of 1 record with delimiter as ^ ...081-09-2355^Sugar Paper Planner 2016 Weekly/Mon^HOME                               ^STAT/HOLIDAY                       ^B081                               ^SCHOOL AND OFFICE SUPPLIES         ^JOURNALS AND PLANNERS              ^SUGAR PAPER       ^ABR28^OTHER             ^2015-10-31^\N^\N^2015-10-20^\N^\N^Blue Sky the Color of Imagination^BLUE SKY THE COLOR OF IMG          ^^GR PRAIRIE  TX^NATIONAL

Comment: Do you want to export data to only 1 column `all_my_columns` ?

Comment: I guess your are trying to say you mentioned all column names (_I assume ,  separated_).

Comment: it's all 21 columns in to separate columns.  All_my_columns refers to all these 21 columns..instead of listing all 21 columns, here I have mentioned in single key word (All_my_columns).  I hope I am clear now.  When I am trying to export all these individual columns into SQL server, it throws error on last column as can't parse string.  I have tried removing the column which it was throwing error, but on the next try it shows error as can't parse on the last column.  Please throw some ideas in resolving this issue.

Comment: if number of columns are same in HDFS and SqlServer, don't add `--columns` By default it will fetch all the columns.

Comment: Thank  you for responding...Initially I have tried without using --columns, but since I am having issue with export command, tried with --columns.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try including this argument?

```
--input-lines-terminated-by <char>
```

i.e

```
--input-lines-terminated-by '\n'
```